# Get specific parts of a string that contains garbage data

Tags: java, android, parsing, urlencode, urldecode

So I have these strings that I'm getting that contains a lot of garbage data which i don't want

```
"http://v20.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?id=271de9756065677e&itag=17&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=999999999999999999"&sparams=ip,ipbits,expireip,ipbits,expire,id,itag&signature=3DCD3F79E045F95B6AF661765F046FB0440FF01606A42661B3AF6BAF046F012549CC9BA34EBC80A9"
```

So basicly I just want it to search trough the string for videoplayback?id=
*and just copy whats between videoplayback?id= and &

> 271de9756065677e

and then continue to go trough the string and Grab the signature in the same way

So anyone can help me with the logic and examples how to do this ?

Comment: You can either iterate through GET parameters and remove it or use regular expressions if you're only dealing with a string representation.

Comment: Could you provide a example how it would look like  @mena ? As I can't figure out how it would look it

Comment: Maybe this will be helpfull: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "string that contains garbage data" is actually a URL you should use the [URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) class
Have a look at the tutorial [Parsing a URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ParseURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "http://v20.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?id=271de9756065677e&itag=17&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=999999999999999999"&sparams=ip,ipbits,expireip,ipbits,expire,id,itag&signature=3DCD3F79E045F95B6AF661765F046FB0440FF01606A42661B3AF6BAF046F012549CC9BA34EBC80A9";
        URL aURL = new URL(url);

        System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
        System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
        System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
        System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
        System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
        System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
    }
}
```

The output should be:

```
protocol = http
authority = v20.lscache8.c.youtube.com:80
host = v20.lscache8.c.youtube.com
port = 80
path = /videoplayback
query = id=271de9756065677e&itag=17&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=999999999999999999"&sparams=ip,ipbits,expireip,ipbits,expire,id,itag&signature=3DCD3F79E045F95B6AF661765F046FB0440FF01606A42661B3AF6BAF046F012549CC9BA34EBC80A9
```

In order to parse the query, use  [URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html)

```
String url = "http://v20.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?id=271de9756065677e&itag=17&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=999999999999999999"&sparams=ip,ipbits,expireip,ipbits,expire,id,itag&signature=3DCD3F79E045F95B6AF661765F046FB0440FF01606A42661B3AF6BAF046F012549CC9BA34EBC80A9";
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");

for (NameValuePair param : params) {
  System.out.println(param.getName() + "=" + param.getValue());
}
```

The output should be:

```
id=271de9756065677e
itag=17
ip=0.0.0.0
ipbits=0
expire=999999999999999999"
sparams=ip,ipbits,expireip,ipbits,expire,id,itag
signature=3DCD3F79E045F95B6AF661765F046FB0440FF01606A42661B3AF6BAF046F012549CC9BA34EBC80A9
```